# python dictionary to duplicated list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do you convert a dictionary to a duplicated list in python?

For example: `{'a':1,'b':2,'c':1,'d':3}` to `['a','b','b','c','d','d','d']`

Answer (score 5):

[`Counter.elements`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) from the collections module does exactly that:

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':1,'d':3}
from collections import Counter
print sorted(Counter(d).elements())
# ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```

Comment: +1, this is really elegant. Perhaps an `OrderDict` could help avoid the sorting step?

Comment: @1_CR that would be changing the input data

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as a nested list comprehension:

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':1,'d':3}
d2 = [k for k, v in d.items() for _ in range(v)]
# ['a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```

However, note that the order will be arbitrary (since dictionary keys have no ordering). If you wanted it to be alphabetical order, do

```
d2 = [k for k, v in sorted(d.items()) for _ in range(v)]
# ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':1,'d':3}
result = [x for k, v in d.items() for x in k * v]
```

Or if you want to ensure a sorted order:

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':1,'d':3}
result = [x for k in sorted(d) for x in k * d[k]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.repeat` is faster. If `D={'a':1,'b':2,'c':1,'d':3}, result=['a','b','b','c','d','d','d']`.

```
from itertools import repeat
result=reduce(lambda la,lb:la+lb,[list(itertools.repeat(k,v)) for k,v in D.items()],[])
```

A much clear way,

```
from itertools import repeat
result=[]
for k,v in D.items():
    result+=list(repeat(k,v))
```

ps.

假设你用的OrderedDict。稍微解释一下第一种。reduce有三个参数，目标是把你字典产生的list，通过最后一个初始值［］，来不断reduce为一个结果list。“你字典产生的list” 就是通过items（）生成的（key，value）这种pair的list。

Comment: what exactly does "假设你用的OrderedDict。稍微解释一下第一种。reduce有三个参数，目标是把你字典产生的list，通过最后一个初始值［］，来不断reduce为一个结果list。“你字典产生的list” 就是通过items（）生成的（key，value）这种pair的list。" mean?